# Nullable list parameter in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I was trying to implement a version of the head function that accepts a "null" parameter

```hs
safeHead :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe b
safeHead (Just []) = Nothing
safeHead Nothing = Nothing
safeHead (Just (x:xs)) = Just x
```

Conceptually it looked ok to me. But the type system doesn't accept the latest equation.
Why ?

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          safeHead :: forall a b. Maybe [a] -> Maybe b
        at ch04.hs:2:1-32
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          safeHead :: forall a b. Maybe [a] -> Maybe b
        at ch04.hs:2:1-32
    • In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely ‘x’
      In the expression: Just x
      In an equation for ‘safeHead’: safeHead (Just (x : xs)) = Just x
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at ch04.hs:4:19)
        x :: a (bound at ch04.hs:4:17)
        safeHead :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe b (bound at ch04.hs:3:1)
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap the argument in `Maybe`. `safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a` is just fine. `[]` *is* the null value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type variables like `a` and `b` in your type signature

```
safeHead :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe b
```

are chosen by the function *caller*. This means that if someone calls your function, they could choose to use it as if it were, say

```
safeHead :: Maybe [String] -> Maybe Int
```

In this scenario, the caller is not satisfied by your third equation

```
safeHead (Just (x:xs)) = Just x
```

since there `x` is a `String`, not an `Int` as the type signature implies.

To fix the code, we need to weaken our type-promise: the function does not return `Maybe b` for all `b`, but only for `b = a`. Hence, we need to use

```
safeHead :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe a
                            -- ^ --
```

Finally, note that usually this kind of "safe head" function is defined with type `[a] -> Maybe a`. I wonder if the additional `Maybe` on the input is really needed. There's nothing wrong with the additional `Maybe` -- but it might not be what you actually need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Maybe on the input parameter was for experimentation on my side. Because after all, if you chain functions returning Maybe, they must also be prepared to process Maybe parameters as input.

Comment: @creatldd1creatldd1 Actually, it's usually most convenient to chain functions of the form `A -> Maybe B`. The `Monad` (and `Applicative`) instance for `Maybe` makes it very easy to combine such functions using operators like `>>=`, `<=<`, etc; these operators themselves will take care of handling when you get a `Nothing` at some stage in the middle of the chain, short circuiting and making sure the remaining functions in the chain are never even called. That way you get to write your functions as actually receiving a value; they are only concerned with their own "failures", not upstream ones.

Answer (score 3):

It is almost correct, except for the type. The result is `Maybe a`, since we take the first item of a list:

```
safeHead :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead (Just []) = Nothing
safeHead Nothing = Nothing
safeHead (Just (x : xs)) = Just x
```

we can also simplify the implementation with:

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

safeHead :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead = (>>= listToMaybe)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How type variables are actually bound is still fuzzy to me.  Interesting tip at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The safety issue that a `safeHead` function would be concerned with is receiving an empty list as input, whether or not it is wrapped as a `Just` value. The argument type remains `[a]`; only the return type is lifted from `a` to `Maybe a`.

```
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead [] = Nothing  -- instead of an error
safeHead (x:_) = Just x
```

Using `safeHead` on a `Maybe [a]` value (such as returned by a `safeTail` function, for example) is done using the `Monad` instance for `Maybe`.

```
safeTail :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
safeTail [] = Nothing
safeTail (_:xs) = Just xs
```

Then

```
> safeTail [] >>= safeHead -- Nothing >>= safeHead
Nothing
> safeTail [1] >>= safeHead  -- Just [] >>= safeHead
Nothing
> safeTail [1,2] >>= safeHead -- Just [2] >>= safeHead
Just 2
```